# .NET Maui TabBar und IOS causes black Appscreen at start

Tags: ios, maui

Inserting the following code in my .NET Maui project works under android, but under ios it causes the app to start and present just a black screen.

Is there a special behavior und IOS for the tabbar icons?

```
   <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="reshot.svg"  >
            <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Page1" Icon="dotnet_bot.svg">
            <ShellContent Title="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" Route="Page1" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Page2" Icon="dotnet_bot.svg" >
            <ShellContent Title="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" Route="Page2" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Page3" Icon="dotnet_bot.svg" >
            <ShellContent Title="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" Route="Page1" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Page4" Icon="dotnet_bot.svg"  >
            <ShellContent Title="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" Route="Page2" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tested with the same code as yours and no black screen occurs, it works fine. The VS version I use is 17.4.2, and the simulator is iPhone13 iOS16.1.

Comment: Yes, thank you. After clearing the cache and deleting everything in the debug and obj folder the error was gone.

Comment: Perhaps this issue is related: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14421

Answer (score 4):

On iOS you should remove the .svg extension, that worked for me, now it no longer shows the black screen.

Result:

```
 <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="reshot">
            <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Page1" Icon="dotnet_bot">
            <ShellContent Title="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" Route="Page1" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Page2" Icon="dotnet_bot" >
            <ShellContent Title="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" Route="Page2" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Page3" Icon="dotnet_bot" >
            <ShellContent Title="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" Route="Page1" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Page4" Icon="dotnet_bot"  >
            <ShellContent Title="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" Route="Page2" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Comment: Thanks, had the exact same issue and your suggestion helped.